# Web scraping international trade data

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, pandas

I'm trying to scrape arrival data from [this website](https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country). My script takes extremely long time to scrape the data. Is there any way I can speed up the scraping process?

Here's my script:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import copy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getBalanceofTrade():
    cookies = {
        '_ga': 'GA1.3.672481365.1630462756',
        'sc_is_visitor_unique': 'rx12421317.1631602001.FE09E031FA464FEEAD095B438DD92829.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2',
        '_ga_41205092': 'GS1.1.1631601995.2.0.1631602551.0',
        'varient_csrf_cookie': 'c34f577f894740d92106453d293f69b4',
        'ci_session': 'q9qvice0p2dgnp5f50veghgrqeveavrm',
        '_gid': 'GA1.3.542540031.1635307774',
        '_gat_gtag_UA_155890962_1': '1',
        'f5avr0338662302aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_cspm_': 'DMPCJNDKGKPBLIDLCKDBLLDGAEPJPBKDHBPPMIDGKFDEMKGDHFNEBJBDOLAMKFJACFDCDGKEHKFEFIPPNNKAJEACAPLNMFADDKOEHBJBKJGGDMKBNHHFMJBOEGLPMEPA',}

    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'Origin': 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',}
    
    base_params = {
        'varient_csrf_token': 'c34f577f894740d92106453d293f69b4',
        'category': 'country'}
    
    value_id = pd.read_excel('Value ID Countries.xlsx')
    value_dict = dict(zip(value_id['VALUE ID'], value_id['COUNTRY']))
    
    params_list = []
    
    for key, value in value_dict.items():
        new_params = copy.copy(base_params)
        new_params['region_id'] = key
        params_list.append(new_params)
    df_all = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for params in params_list:
        response = requests.post('https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-query', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=params)
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        df1 = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
        #print(df1)
        table_list = df1['data']
        for table in table_list:
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table)
            df_all = df_all.append(df, ignore_index=True)
            
    country = []
    for i in value_id['COUNTRY']:
        x = [i] * len(df)
        country.append(x)
        
    country_list = [item for s in country for item in s]
    
    df_all['Country'] = country_list
    
    df_new = df_all.iloc[:, 0:6]
    df_new1 = df_all.iloc[:, 8:9]
    df_new2 = df_all.iloc[:, 10:11]
    result = pd.concat([df_new, df_new1, df_new2], axis=1)
    
    URL = 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table =soup.find('table', id="table-balance")
    rows = table.find_all('th')
    cols = [item.text.strip() for item in rows]
     #column name uraian
    column_name = [cols[0]]
    column_name1 = cols[1:6]
    column_name2 = [cols[10]]
    tahun = column_name1 + column_name2
    final_column = column_name + column_name1 + column_name2 + ['Country']
    result.columns = final_column
    
    desc_1 = 3*(result['Uraian'][0],)
    desc_2 = 3*(result['Uraian'][3],)
    desc_3 = 3*(result['Uraian'][6],)
    desc_4 = 3*(result['Uraian'][9],)
    x = desc_1 + desc_2 + desc_3 + desc_4
    y = list(x)
    z = y * len(value_id['COUNTRY'])
    result = result.replace(['TOTAL PERDAGANGAN', 'EKSPOR', 'IMPOR', 'NERACA PERDAGANGAN'], ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total']) 
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(z, columns=['description'])
    
    result = result.rename(columns = {'Uraian': 'tipe'}, inplace = False)
    table = pd.concat ([df2, result], axis=1)
    
    df_table = table.melt(id_vars=['description', 'tipe', 'Country'], value_vars=tahun, var_name='year')
    
    return(df_table)
```

Excel file:

```
VALUE ID | COUNTRY
147         ADEN
137         AFGANISTAN
299         AFRIKA LAINNYA
...           ...
```

Comment: What is the reason that your output is in Pandas format?

Comment: Should we presume the Excel file has 195 countries in it? The first solution to speedup I'd try is to parallelize that `for` loop; use [threads or asyncio to request 20 at a time or so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996653/6243352). But without a bit more detail I can't run or mess with the code in a meaningful way to test this hypothesis.

Comment: @ggorlen it has 279 countries in it

Comment: when you click [this website](https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country) then right-click on that page then click view-source, on that page it contains the ids and the countries  @ggorlen

Answer (score 4):

It won't be practical to speed this process up since you're scraping a third-party website. Parallelizing requests and loading the server is ethically dubious so I think you don't have many options other than to be patient.

`getBalanceofTrade` should be `get_balance_of_trade` by PEP8.

This function mixes together far too many concerns:

- session cookie & header construction (which is hard-coded when it should not be)
- fetching and parsing two different pages
- loading a country database
- data cleaning
- construction of a dataframe

Each of these should be separate. Your requests should use an actual `Session` object. If you first run a request to `balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country` before the actual data fetching, it can serve two purposes: initialize a fresh (not hard-coded) CSRF token, and fetch your country database. You then won't need an Excel file at all (which should not have been an Excel file - it should have been something more machine-readable like a CSV).

The country database `get` should use a strainer to only parse the portion of the HTML document containing region IDs. If you want to be fancy, you can also pre-compile your CSS selectors via `soupsieve`.

You should drop nearly all of your hard-coded headers and cookies and pass only

- cookies given to you automatically via `Session`, and
- an `Accept` header correctly communicating what content type you're expecting (even though the server is broken and returns the wrong content type for JSON).

You should not `json.loads`, and should instead call `response.json()`. The response should also be used in a context management `with`.

An example implementation that addresses some of these concerns:

```
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Iterator, Tuple, Any, Dict
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import soupsieve
from bs4 import SoupStrainer, BeautifulSoup, ResultSet
from requests import Session


BASE = 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id'


COUNTRY_DROPDOWN = SoupStrainer(name='select', id='country')
OPTION_SIEVE = soupsieve.compile(pattern=':root > option:not([value=""])')


def get_regions(session: Session) -> Iterator[Tuple[str, int]]:
    with session.get(
        url=urljoin(BASE, 'balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country'),
        headers={'Accept': 'text/html'},
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(
            markup=resp.text,
            features='html.parser', parse_only=COUNTRY_DROPDOWN,
        )

    for option in OPTION_SIEVE.select(doc):
        name = option.text.strip().title()
        value = int(option['value'])
        yield name, value


def query_balance(session: Session, region_id: int) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    with session.post(
        urljoin(BASE, 'balance-query'),
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
        data={
            'region_id': region_id,
            'category': 'country',
            'varient_csrf_token': session.cookies['varient_csrf_cookie'],
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return resp.json()


def main() -> None:
    with Session() as session:
        regions = dict(get_regions(session))
        data = query_balance(session, regions['Kanada'])  # 412
        pprint(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the one country queried, this prints

```json
{'country': 'KANADA',
 'data': [{'cumulative_1': '1,597,724.5',
           'cumulative_2': '2,049,001.3',
           'growth': '28.24',
           'period_1': '2,115,477.3',
           'period_2': '2,374,859.0',
           'period_3': '2,754,638.7',
           'period_4': '2,696,923.0',
           'period_5': '2,404,576.7',
           'trend': '3.91',
           'uraian': 'TOTAL PERDAGANGAN'},
          {'cumulative_1': '276.7',
           'cumulative_2': '528.8',
           'growth': '91.10',
           'period_1': '633.8',
           'period_2': '772.1',
           'period_3': '1,155.0',
           'period_4': '709.6',
           'period_5': '407.8',
           'trend': '-9.21',
           'uraian': 'MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '1,597,447.8',
           'cumulative_2': '2,048,472.5',
           'growth': '28.23',
           'period_1': '2,114,843.4',
           'period_2': '2,374,086.9',
           'period_3': '2,753,483.7',
           'period_4': '2,696,213.4',
           'period_5': '2,404,168.9',
           'trend': '3.91',
           'uraian': 'NON MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '497,670.5',
           'cumulative_2': '675,889.8',
           'growth': '35.81',
           'period_1': '732,447.3',
           'period_2': '821,233.1',
           'period_3': '913,889.2',
           'period_4': '858,206.0',
           'period_5': '789,116.4',
           'trend': '1.95',
           'uraian': 'EKSPOR'},
          {'cumulative_1': '24.4',
           'cumulative_2': 0,
           'growth': '0.00',
           'period_1': '121.4',
           'period_2': '100.0',
           'period_3': '123.1',
           'period_4': '86.3',
           'period_5': '24.4',
           'trend': '-28.52',
           'uraian': 'MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '497,646.1',
           'cumulative_2': '675,889.8',
           'growth': '35.82',
           'period_1': '732,326.0',
           'period_2': '821,133.1',
           'period_3': '913,766.1',
           'period_4': '858,119.7',
           'period_5': '789,092.0',
           'trend': '1.95',
           'uraian': 'NON MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '1,100,054.0',
           'cumulative_2': '1,373,111.5',
           'growth': '24.82',
           'period_1': '1,383,029.9',
           'period_2': '1,553,625.8',
           'period_3': '1,840,749.5',
           'period_4': '1,838,717.0',
           'period_5': '1,615,460.4',
           'trend': '4.91',
           'uraian': 'IMPOR'},
          {'cumulative_1': '252.3',
           'cumulative_2': '528.8',
           'growth': '109.57',
           'period_1': '512.5',
           'period_2': '672.1',
           'period_3': '1,031.9',
           'period_4': '623.3',
           'period_5': '383.5',
           'trend': '-6.34',
           'uraian': 'MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '1,099,801.6',
           'cumulative_2': '1,372,582.7',
           'growth': '24.80',
           'period_1': '1,382,517.4',
           'period_2': '1,552,953.8',
           'period_3': '1,839,717.6',
           'period_4': '1,838,093.7',
           'period_5': '1,615,076.9',
           'trend': '4.91',
           'uraian': 'NON MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '-602,383.5',
           'cumulative_2': '-697,221.7',
           'growth': '-15.74',
           'period_1': '-650,582.6',
           'period_2': '-732,392.7',
           'period_3': '-926,860.2',
           'period_4': '-980,511.0',
           'period_5': '-826,344.0',
           'trend': '-8.00',
           'uraian': 'NERACA PERDAGANGAN'},
          {'cumulative_1': '-228.0',
           'cumulative_2': '-528.8',
           'growth': '-131.99',
           'period_1': '-391.1',
           'period_2': '-572.0',
           'period_3': '-908.8',
           'period_4': '-537.0',
           'period_5': '-359.1',
           'trend': '2.31',
           'uraian': 'MIGAS'},
          {'cumulative_1': '-602,155.5',
           'cumulative_2': '-696,692.8',
           'growth': '-15.70',
           'period_1': '-650,191.5',
           'period_2': '-731,820.6',
           'period_3': '-925,951.5',
           'period_4': '-979,974.0',
           'period_5': '-825,984.9',
           'trend': '-8.01',
           'uraian': 'NON MIGAS'}],
 'period': '2016 - 2021'}
```

Comment: what if my expected output is dataframe of all the country data? @Reinderien

Comment: @lockey You never answered : why a dataframe?

Comment: because it will store to postgres base on that dataframe format

Comment: You're concerned about performance: a more performant solution will skip Pandas altogether, use a direct engine library like psycopg, and split off an asynchronous insert while the next web record is being fetched.

Comment: what do u mean with ```split off an asynchronous ```? @Reinderien

Comment: what if scraping all countries in one time? @Reinderien

Comment: _what if scraping all countries in one time?_ - If you don't own the website, don't do that. It's discourteous and can be construed as a DOS.